# Saving changes from multiple ASP.NET Telerik grids via one submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a complex screen that has two telerik grids as well as other user controls (text boxes, dropdowns, etc).  Users can add/delete/edit rows in both of the grids and both of the grids are inter-related (one uses data from another)

I need to have one form submit that would package all of the data and send it to one ActionResult inside a controller.  Telerik's examples show how to submit one grid at a time, but can this be done across multiple grids and other controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you encounter is quite frequently discussed on the forums.
Here is one discussion : 
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/submit-entire-form-including-grids.aspx

Comment: unfortunately this link doesn't work anymore so whatever the answer is was lost